# Imagemagick jpeg decode delegate missing with OS X Homebrew install

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I recently converted from macports to homebrew and my previous macports Imagemagick install was working fine. I followed the homebrew instructions to chown /usr/local (somewhat apprehensively) and remove /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib. When trying to work with any jpeg images, imagemagick chokes with:

> no decode delegate for this image format

Here is a list of some relevant command output. As you can see, no jpeg/jpg delegate can be found.

`convert -list configure` =>
`DELEGATES     bzlib freetype png x11 xml zlib`

`identify -list configure` => `DELEGATES     bzlib freetype png x11 xml zlib`

However, jpeg lib was installed as part of the Imagemagick dependencies, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

`brew list` => `imagemagick jasper      jpeg        libtiff     little-cms  nginx       pcre`

`brew doctor` => `Your OS X is ripe for brewing. Any troubles you may be experiencing are likely purely psychosomatic.`

`identify --version` => `Version: ImageMagick 6.6.7-9 2011-04-06 Q16`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Andrei, your solution got me in the right direction.

but it was a

```
brew install --force jpeg
brew install --force imagemagick
```

that got it working for me.

Comment: I had a similar problem getting the `lqr` delegate to work. I had to `brew unlink imagemagick` and then `brew install --force liblqr` and `brew install --force imagemagick` to clear it up. Thanks!

Comment: Problem fixed here, as well. Thank you!

Comment: I started with `brew uninstall jpeg` and `brew uninstall imagemagick`. Then did `brew install --force jpeg` and `brew install --force imagemagick`. Worked on Mavericks 10.9.4. I also upgraded to the latest xQuartz http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this issue myself. While investigating I noticed symlinks to the jpeg jib were missing from /usr/local/lib. Can take of this with the following; just be sure to refer to the jpeg lib version in use, at the time of this post I am using 8c:

```
 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8c/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib

 ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8c/lib/libjpeg.a /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
```

Then force homebrew to reinstall imagemagick:

```
 brew install --force imagemagick
```

Viola! Imagemagick will now show that a jpeg delegate is present.

Comment: Thanks, working well to me, actually i just link the lib, no need reinstall/install force imagemagick

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the direction pointed. My jpeg is also already in the delegate list, re-installing imagemagick doesn't work for me, but relinking jpeg does:

```
brew unlink jpeg
brew link jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out to be permissions.

```
sudo chown myuser:wheel /usr/local
```

then:

```
brew remove jpeg
brew remove imagemagick
brew install jpeg
brew install imagemagick
```

sorted it.
Word of warning though: I had MySQL sittting in /usr/local/ too, and I inadvertently messed up permissions for that, so if you've got anything else important in there, be careful :-)
Fixed that with:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:wheel /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This was my problem after upgrading to Mavericks too - except I didn't have to chown anything, just the uninstall and reinstall of jpeg and imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

9monkeys solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715738/imagemagick-error) **plus restarting Terminal** worked for me.