# ImageMagick error

Tags: imagemagick, node-imagemagick

When trying to run ImageMagick via node-imagemagick on my Grunt task, i get this error from ImageMagick:

> Warning: Command failed: identify: unable to load module
>   `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la':
>   file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275. identify: no decode
>   delegate for this image format`inventaire/videos/OFF_Arrestation
>   joueur_14_petit.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.  Use --force
>   to continue.

Why is ImageMagick trying to load JPG coder at `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la`? Why the double slash after `ImageMagick//` ?

This grunt script run perfectly on OSX 10.8 and now fail on 10.9.2.
Anyone know a way to fix it?

Comment: Hey Dominic, did @emcconville's solution work for you? I am getting the same error with Imagemagick and paperclip.

Answer (score 23):

I came across this issue too when upgrading from Mt.Lion to Mavericks. I found [an issue in homebrew's github repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/14325).  The fix that worked for me was:

```
$ brew uninstall imagemagick
$ brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Comment: this was ultimately the solution that worked for me following an upgrade from Mt Lion -> Mavericks

Comment: If you are getting a 404 error when building from source, make sure you've updated (and maybe upgraded) homebrew.

Answer (score 17):

OSX Mavericks seems break the link of jpeg lib. All you need to do is relink the jpeg, then reinstall imagemagick.

```
brew unlink jpeg
brew link jpeg
```

Then reinstall imagemagick from source

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Now you can check if jpeg is in the delegate

```
identify -list configure | grep DELEGATES
```

It should have jpeg now

> DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg lcms lzma png tiff xml zlib

Comment: In my case, just `brew unlink jpeg`/`brew link jpeg` made the trick.

Comment: In my case, `brew unlink jpeg`/`brew link jpeg` alone did NOT do the trick, but adding `brew uninstall imagemagick`/`brew install imagemagick --build-from-source` (which took about 6 minutes) did indeed do the trick!

Answer (score 6):

This is what finally worked for me after a bunch of installs and uninstalls. I removed and reinstalled imagemagick with these options

`brew install imagemagick --with-fontconfig --with-ghostscript --with-libtiff --with-webp`

I am only using `jpeg` and `png` for now, and am not sure how these options help, but worth a try.

Comment: This also works without the flag `--with-ghostscript`

Comment: I had to remove `graphicsmagick` to be able to install `imagemagick` properly.

Comment: I had the same problem. Following [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29708), and running `brew unlink libpng && brew link --overwrite libpng` fixed it for me. The **overwrite** was what made it work.

Comment: thank you so much... i tried so many things. this finally worked for me

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick@6 
brew install imagemagick@6 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick's module dependencies are out of date by the systems upgrade. You'll need to re-install homebrew packages. See this articles "[Upgrading homebrew packages on OSX Mavericks](http://jameshalsall.co.uk/posts/upgrading-homebrew-packages-on-osx-mavericks)", or "[Install ImageMagicK on OSX Lion](https://sethvargo.com/install-imagemagick-on-osx-lion/)."

> Why is ImageMagick trying to load JPG coder at
>   /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.8-9/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la

ImageMagick is expecting a static library for JPEG. The module is simply not there, or unreadable.

> Why the double slash after ImageMagick// ?

This is common with homebrew. It's safe, and will resolve to  `ImageMagick/`.

> ... know a way to fix it?

Run the followin in Terminal.app

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew update
brew cleanup
brew doctor
brew install imagemagick
```

Comment: Did all that, still get `convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1282.`